# How can you speed up accessing contacts on Android?

Tags: android, contacts

Seems to me that accessing contacts on Android is so slow, and needlessly involves cursors. How can it be sped up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.When the first time you read the contact, you may reduce some property.

2.When reading a type of property, you may use a cursor.

```
private static final String[] CONTACTOR_ION = new String[]{  
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,  
ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,  
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER  
};  


Cursor phones = null;  
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();  
try {  
phones = cr  
        .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI  
                , CONTACTOR_ION, null, null, "sort_key");  

if (phones != null) {  
    final int contactIdIndex = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID);  
    final int displayNameIndex = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);  
    final int phoneIndex = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);  
    String phoneString, displayNameString, contactIdString;  
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {   
        phoneString = phones.getString(phoneIndex);  
        displayNameString = phones.getString(displayNameIndex);  
        contactIdString = phones.getString(contactIdIndex);  
    }  
}  
          } catch (Exception e) {  
Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());  
} finally {  
if (phones != null)  
    phones.close();  
}
```

Comment: What is linkManForm for?

Comment: @SomeGuy Oh, it's an object used to save LinkMan info, I will edit my code and remove this line.